# Problema com acesso ao Tomcat no momento da implantação

Tags: java-ee, tomcat, netbeans

Estou a trabalhar em um projeto de JavaEE no NetBeans 8.0.1 utilizando o Tomcat 8.0.9 como container. O problema se dá no momento da execução do projeto, a IDE pede um usuário e senha e eu os forneço, porém ela os ignora e pede novamente, clico em cancelar e acusa o seguinte:

```
Erro de Implantação: O acesso ao servidor Tomcat não foi autorizado. Defina corretamente o nome de usuário e a senha com a atribuição \"manager-script\" no personalizador do Tomcat no gerenciador do servidor.
```

O problema é que coloco o usuário/senha exatamente como está no gerenciador do servidor e simplesmente não funciona, também tentei colocar os dados que estão atribuídos ao *manager-script* no arquivo *tomcat-users.xml* e também não funcionou, outra coisa que tentei foi modificar a senha do no próprio gerenciador do servidor no NetBeans e ele não o fez, continuou a mesma.

Como posso resolver ou pelo menos contornar este problema?

---

Não sei se isso pode influenciar em algo, mas instalei o Tomcat no momento da instalação do NetBeans (ele veio junto com a IDE).

Comment: Está usando linux? No ubuntu tem como editar o arquivo texto que tem essa configuração, no Windows deve ter também, mas daí não sei onde.

Comment: Na realidade, eu já o editei (*tomcat-users.xml*), mas ele "ignora" essa edição e não aceita como usuário.

Comment: Editei minha resposta, não sei se tu recebe notificação, aquela ali deve resolver.

Answer (score 1):

Edita o tomcat-users.xml e adiciona o role "manager-script"

```
<user username="ide" password="xxx" roles="manager-script,admin"/>
```

Comment: O fiz, não funcionou. Também tentei colocar a senha igual ao do gerenciador do NetBeans e deu no mesmo, não funciona.

Comment: Obrigado Luiz Rossi, estava com este mesmo problema e consegui resolver com sua dica.

Answer (score 0):

Tive exatamente este mesmo problema. Resolvi fazendo alterações no tomcat-users.xml
O meu ficou assim:

```
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="admin"/>
<role rolename="tomcat"/>
<role rolename="role1"/>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager-script,admin,tomcat,role1, admin-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

No netbeans, fui na aba "Ferramentas", no item "Servidores". Cliquei no tomcat e inseri "tomcat" e "tomcat" em nome de usuario e senha.

Answer (score 0):

Procurei durante horas uma solução, não estava conseguindo acessar nem o Web Manager, nem o Server Status e nem o Host Manager, até chegar aqui, utilizei a dica do [MCGBra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/22424/mcgbra), consegui acesso ao Host Manager e ao Server Status, mas o Web Manager estava ainda dando o erro 403 de acesso negado. Foi então que acrescentei uma linha ao arquivo e deu certo.

Linha acrescentada: `<role rolename="manager-gui"/>`  e no roles também `roles="manager-script,manager-gui,admin,tomcat,role1, admin-gui"/>`

Ficando o meu arquivo completo assim:

```
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"              version="1.0">
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="admin"/>
<role rolename="tomcat"/>
<role rolename="role1"/>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager-script,manager-gui,admin,tomcat,role1,admin-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Muito obrigado por compartilhar esta dica [MCGBra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/22424/mcgbra), agora está funcionando perfeitamente. Vlw mesmo!!!