# Problema na inicialização do Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, xampp

Como medida paliativa para [este erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38812/), instalei o XAMPP e o coloquei (o Tomcat) como container para o NetBeans. Porém quando vou executar algum projeto no NetBeans, o seguinte erro aparece no console do Tomcat na IDE:

```
Iniciando a partir da falha do Tomcat:

'127.0.0.1' nÆo ‚ reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa oper vel ou um arquivo em lotes.
```

E o processo de implantação do projeto é interrompido.

Acho isso estranho, porque quando tento iniciar o Tomcat diretamente pelo XAMPP, ele o faz normalmente. Tentei iniciar o NetBeans como administrador, mas não funcionou. Como posso resolvê-lo?

Comment: @perdeu, sim, Windows. Como eu poderia checar esse *path*?

Comment: @perdeu, quando você diz "instalado como serviço", quer dizer que ele inicia automaticamente com o Windows? Se sim, não, não o instalei como serviço, apenas prossegui pela instalação padrão do XAMPP. Quanto à variável `path`: `%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin`; o que deveria estar aí, mas não está?

Comment: @perdeu, não resolveu, mas receio que você não entendeu o problema, vou editar a pergunta.

Comment: O problema parece estar no NetBeans, não no Tomcat.

Answer (score 20):

Por algum motivo esse problema tem a ver com as configurações de proxy do Netbeans.

Se você for no menu Ferramentas -> Opções e marcar a opção "Sem Proxy" nas "Definições de Proxy" deve iniciar corretamente o tomcat.

Comment: Ótima resposta Luiz Feltes! Ajudou bastante!!